# go get - proxy.golang.org connection refused

Tags: go

while installing or getting any kind of dependency with `go get` or `go install` I'll get a connection refused error.

```
 > go install github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/cmd/golangci-lint@latest
go: github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/cmd/golangci-lint@latest: module github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/cmd/golangci-lint: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/cmd/golangci-lint/@v/list": dial tcp: lookup proxy.golang.org on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:53273->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
```

`curl` and `git clone` are working. What could be the problem?

go env:

```
GO111MODULE=''
GOARCH='amd64'
GOBIN=''
GOCACHE='/home/micro/.cache/go-build'
GOENV='/home/micro/.config/go/env'
GOEXE=''
GOEXPERIMENT=''
GOFLAGS=''
GOHOSTARCH='amd64'
GOHOSTOS='linux'
GOINSECURE=''
GOMODCACHE='/home/micro/.local/share/go/pkg/mod'
GONOPROXY=''
GONOSUMDB=''
GOOS='linux'
GOPATH='/home/micro/.local/share/go'
GOPRIVATE=''
GOPROXY='https://proxy.golang.org,direct'
GOROOT='/usr/lib/go'
GOSUMDB='sum.golang.org'
GOTMPDIR=''
GOTOOLCHAIN='auto'
GOTOOLDIR='/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64'
GOVCS=''
GOVERSION='go1.21.1'
GCCGO='gccgo'
GOAMD64='v1'
AR='ar'
CC='gcc'
CXX='g++'
CGO_ENABLED='1'
GOMOD='/dev/null'
GOWORK=''
CGO_CFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_CPPFLAGS=''
CGO_CXXFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_FFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_LDFLAGS='-O2 -g'
PKG_CONFIG='pkg-config'
GOGCCFLAGS='-fPIC -m64 -pthread -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -ffile-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build1574177678=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches'
```

Comment: do you tested VPN, restart system,  DNS??

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I'm facing the same issue and I haven't been able to find anything related online. All other network components are working as intended (DNS, no VPN, etc...) but `go get ...` fails with the above error.

Comment: So I don't really know how that dns works, because curl, ping or git was working, but I've added `nameserver 8.8.8.8` in `/etc/resolv.conf` and now it works.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick for me as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `systemd-resolved` you need to replace `/etc/resolv.conf` with `systemd-resolved` stub symlink.

```
ln -sf ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

> To provide domain name resolution for software that reads
> /etc/resolv.conf directly, such as web browsers, Go and GnuPG,
> systemd-resolved has four different modes for handling the file—stub,
> static, uplink and foreign. They are described in systemd-resolved(8)
> § /ETC/RESOLV.CONF. We will focus here only on the recommended mode,
> i.e. the stub mode which uses /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf.
>
> /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf contains the local stub
> 127.0.0.53 as the only DNS server and a list of search domains. This is the recommended mode of operation that propagates the
> systemd-resolved managed configuration to all clients. To use it,
> replace /etc/resolv.conf with a symbolic link to it:
>
> ```
> ln -sf ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
> ```

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-resolved#DNS